# HP DL360 G5. Doesn't start if power cable plugged in PSU1

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I bought an used server. When I plugged in a first PSU (the one near sidewall) a power cable, some fans turned on, a led on the front panel light orange, on mobo green leds works. When I press a power button nothing happens. 
When I plugged off the cable from the first PSU and plugged in the second PSU, some fans turned on, led on the front panel light orange, on mobo green leds works. If I press the power button the server boots with a warning, that power is not redundant.
Is PSU 1 dead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to the people or company you purchased the used server from. This isn't something that we should be troubleshooting since there's no context.

If this were a server that you owned for its lifetime, then the best course of action would be to call manufacturer support.

Comment: Well, I'm of course could return the server to the seller, there is some moneyback period, but I bought it with a good discount and I like it even if PSU 1 is dead. Probably, if PSU is, indeed, the problem, I could buy another one. I just don't sure. I don't have HP servers or any servers with 2 PSUs earlier, so I don't know is it normal or not. As I mentioned, it starts fans, leds and so on, but do not start the server. If you could give some valued advice, you can ask any context you wanted, the server is just behind my desk.

Comment: Oh, this is not normal. Your PSU may be dead. Please try swapping the two PSU units to see if it's the actual PSU or the motherboard slot.

Comment: I swapped PSUs between themselves. It looks PSU 1 is a malfunction, indeed.